# Constrain a Array<string> formula result to a list in a single cell

Tags: google-sheets, concatenate

I'm using a formula that returns an Array of strings, so the result overwrites a range of cells, but I want to get the result in just that one cell.

(The actual formula I'm using is WIKISYNONYMS from a 3rd party add-on, but that shouldn't matter.)

I tried using ARRAY_CONSTRAIN, eg.

```
=ARRAY_CONSTRAIN( WIKISYNONYMS("en:Berlin"), 1, 1 )
```

But that throws away all the data that would have gone beyond the constraints, rather then constraining all the data to that one cell.

So I tried using concatenate, eg.

```
=CONCATENATE( WIKISYNONYMS("en:Berlin") )
```

And that is close, but I need to add ", " or something like that between each entry for readability.

Comment: @pnuts Yes, that does it.  Make it an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [JOIN](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094077) to stitch the pieces together with a given delimiter:

```
=join(",", f o r m u l a )
```

Comment: Ok, and for the sake of completeness I'll note that becomes =join(", ", WIKISYNONYMS(A1)) with my formula if one is OK with trailing comma, otherwise =left(join(",", WIKISYNONYMS(H10) ),len(join(", ", WIKISYNONYMS(A1) ))-2).